# Eclipse 3.6 do not have UML2 Tools?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I'd like to install UML2 Tool plugin in eclipse 3.6, but I can not find it in update-manager

Could anyone help me install this plugin ?

Thanks

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find all UML tools in [Eclipse Market Place ("UML" category](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/19))

The official [UML2 Eclipse project](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=uml2) is still in active development, and can be [downloaded here](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/downloads/?project=uml2).
Plus MDT/UML2 provides only the metamodel, it does not provide UML modelling tools themselves. One implementation is **[MDT-UML2Tools](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2Tools)** (which is not currently updated for Helios and more).

So Eclipse Market place remains the place where you can find more complete UML2 tools.

Answer (score 7):

"UML2 Tools" didn't make the Helios release train. And the version of UML2 Tools that was in Galileo won't work as it has dependencies on a component from MDT/OCL that was removed in the version of that project that went into Helios.

[This FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT/OCL/FAQ#How_do_I_workaround_org.eclipse.emf.ocl_deprecation_in_Helios_and_later.3F) has a complicated workaround.

As others have mentioned, development in the UML2 Tools project seems to have stopped, and Papyrus could be a replacement. The UML2 project at Eclipse (which is a library that implements the UML 2.* metamodel, but does not provide diagramming features) has not died, and [many commercial products and open source projects rely on it](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2-Tool-Compatibility). And no, the UML standard itself hasn't died either, and is undergoing active development.

Answer (score 2):

You have two open source projects (*e.g. Papyrus and Topcased*) and two commercial tools (Omondo EclipseUML and RSA IBM).

btw, UML is really very few uses today.
It seems to me that the GMF project on which Eclipse modeling tools are based is stopped since Eclipse 3.5. A difficult upgrade to 3.6 was made but I doubt that 3.7 will ever be done. I therefore consider that Eclipse 3.6 is the last UML version for Eclipse and no other smart UML tool will be developped on the latest Eclipse indigo 3.7 and further builds.

Answer (score -4):

Dont worry nobody really cares about UML any more. Write better documentation w/ the code rather than silly diagrams that quickly become out of date and you and those that follow will have an easier life.

Comment: I am not sure that that is *entirely* true, but UML tightly integrated with the IDE and code generation has always been a non-starter in my opinion.  Trying to make UML an implementation tool rather than a design tool is very difficult and largely unproductive, so integrating it with the code IDE is almost poitless IMO.

Comment: Show me where Google publishes any UML for Android, Oracle for Java, Microsoft for .net, the community for Python or Ruby or PHP. The actual number is barely a handful of times leaving the vast majority of the frameworks w/out UML. What does that tell you ?

Comment: In industry, on commercial and bespoke projects (where I suggest the vast majority of software development is done more-or-less invisibly to anyone not working within it) UML is a common requirement.  You would do better considering its occurrence in job ads, than one or two well known open-source projects to determine its prevalence and relevance to the industry.  The projects you mentioned may be large and high profile, but are by no means representative of the majority of software development.