# Eclipse: How can I install UML2 Tools

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

I'd like to try UML2 Tools for Eclipse, as shown in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/UML/article.html).

I currently have Eclipse 3.6 Helios for Java EE developers.

In my Eclipse Marketplace I switched marketplace catalog to **Yoxos Marketplace** and there searched for **UML2 Tools SDK(Incubation)**. When I try to install them, Eclipse wont proceed and complains about some conflicting dependencies. Here's whole trace:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: UML2 Tools SDK (Incubation) 0.9.0.v200906190654 (org.eclipse.uml2tools.sdk.feature.group 0.9.0.v200906190654)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    EMF Ecore 2.5.0.v200906151043 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.5.0.v200906151043)
    EMF Ecore 2.6.1.v20100914-1218 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.6.1.v20100914-1218)
    EMF Ecore 2.6.0.v20100614-1136 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.6.0.v20100614-1136)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (epp.package.jee 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.2.20110301-1807]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Object Constraint Language (OCL) 2.0 Compatibility API 1.1.101.v200901271800 (org.eclipse.emf.ocl 1.1.101.v200901271800)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.ocl.ecore [1.1.0,2.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.2.20110301-1807 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.2.20110301-1807)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 3.2.3.v201011031800-7b7GHfIFSK2WBRT6E1mcyFXGPnSh (org.eclipse.jst.enterprise_ui.feature.feature.group 3.2.3.v201011031800-7b7GHfIFSK2WBRT6E1mcyFXGPnSh)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.ui [1.0.301.v201012020511]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JAX-RS Tools - UI 1.0.301.v201012020511 (org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.ui 1.0.301.v201012020511)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.6.0,3.0.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: OCL 2.0 Binding for Ecore 1.3.0.v200905271400 (org.eclipse.ocl.ecore 1.3.0.v200905271400)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore [2.5.0,2.6.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: UML2 Diagramming (Incubation) 0.9.0.v200906190654 (org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.feature.group 0.9.0.v200906190654)
    To: org.eclipse.emf.ocl 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: UML2 Tools SDK (Incubation) 0.9.0.v200906190654 (org.eclipse.uml2tools.sdk.feature.group 0.9.0.v200906190654)
    To: org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.feature.group [0.9.0.v200906190654]
```

Maybe I don't understand whole concept and am trying something inappropriate, I don't know. Thank you for advices.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UML2 Tools has no release that works with Eclipse 3.6 and newer. You could use [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/papyrus/) instead.

Comment: 3.6 has been around for a while, it looks kind of abandoned to me. Do you have more information on this issue?

Comment: Not really. In 3.5 it was part of the release train, in 3.6 no compatible release. However, in the end of the following thread it is stated that the project 'aten't dead': http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=170577&S=05251b00252a477e21bda76cff280c57#msg_542105 I think, either hope the best or switch to Papyrus.

Comment: Ok I think it's best what I can do now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need UML2 Tools 0.9.0 to work in Eclipse Helios 3.6, there is a [workaround](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT/OCL/FAQ#How_do_I_workaround_org.eclipse.emf.ocl_deprecation_in_Helios_and_later.3F) you need to do before installing UML2 Tools as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524542/eclipse-3-6-do-not-have-uml2-tools/4541580#4541580).

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Anyway I am planning to upgrade to Indigo asap an it's ok to keep more than 1 eclipses for me :)