# Eclipse: How to install uml2 Tools SDK in Eclipse 4.3 (kepler)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, eclipse-kepler

I have tried to install UML2 Tools SDK plugin according to [this](http://www.vogella.com/articles/UML/article.html) tutorial in Eclipse 4.3 (kepler) version. I am working with windows 7 OS. But i did't get the solution. will you help me?

Comment: Zoltan's answer is the solution:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318992/eclipse-how-can-i-install-uml2-tools.

Comment: @Athan: they are referring Papyrus..!! It is not a solution, just an option.!!

Answer (score 4):

Just installed this today....

Help -> Install New Software

Work With: **--All Available Sites--**

Expand 'Modeling' branch in the tree.

Select 'UML2 Extender SDK'

Then hit the Next button to install....

Comment: According to your suggestion i had installed "UML 2 Extender SDK". But, when i tried "http://www.vogella.com/articles/UML/article.html" tutorial i am not getting particular steps... Did you work on that before??

Comment: @Rajan that article is from 12/2009, a lot could have changed since then.

Comment: @Tarek can u provide me a link for such new article?

Comment: At this time, the UML2 Extended SDK includes:
1) Source for UML2 End_user Features 2) UML2 Documentation 3) UML2 End-User Features and 4) UML2 Examples. You can see these, if you expand UML2 Extender SDK on the next step.